# how to play a video from a file using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a custom gallery picker using the photo manager package and it works like a charm. but now i want to display the video i get from a file and play the first video. but here is the problem i'm facing.

to use the video player we need to initialize on page first load. and during this load the assets will load at the same time. so it doesn't initialize.

the second problem is that when i select any video that i get from my file it doesn't work correctly. meaning if i select one it displays the first and whenever i select another file it still plays the first video.

here is how i did everything.

in my `Gallery.dart`

```
//to store all the files
List<AssetEntity> assets = []; 

//to store what i select
ValueNotifier<List<File?>> selectedAssets = ValueNotifier<List<File?>>([]);

late VideoPlayerController _controller;

void _playVideo({bool init = false, File? file}) async {
    final vids =
        await assets.where((element) => element.type == AssetType.video);
    if (selectedAssets.value.length == 0) return;

    if (!init) {
      _controller.pause();
    }


    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(file!)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
      ..setLooping(false)
      ..initialize().then((value) => _controller.play());
  }

Future _fetchAssets(RequestType type) async {
    // Set onlyAll to true, to fetch only the 'Recent' album
    // which contains all the photos/videos in the storage
    final albums = await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList(
        onlyAll: true,
        type: type,
        filterOption: FilterOptionGroup(
            videoOption: const FilterOption(
                durationConstraint:
                    DurationConstraint(max: Duration(seconds: 600)))));
    final recentAlbum = albums.first;

    // Now that we got the album, fetch all the assets it contains
    final recentAssets = await recentAlbum.getAssetListRange(
        start: 0, // start at index 0
        // end: 1000000, // end at a very big index (to get all the assets)
        end: 1000000);

    // Update the state and notify UI
    setState(() => assets = recentAssets);
  }


 @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchAssets(type);
    _playVideo(init: true);
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

after this i created the top section where it displays the selected video / image

? !isVideo
? AssetThumbnail(
controller: _controller,
asset: assets[0],
selectedAssets:
selectedAssets,
blurhash: blurhash,
)
: AssetThumbnail(
controller: _controller,
asset: assets[0],
selectedAssets:
selectedAssets,
blurhash: blurhash,
)
: !isVideo
? Container(
height: _height * 0.5,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
image: FileImage(
value.last!))),
)
: _controller
.value.isInitialized
? ValueListenableBuilder(
valueListenable:
selectedAssets,
builder: (context,
value1, child) {
return VideoPlayer(
_controller);
})
: Container(),

then i have created gridview to display the files. then in my AssetThumbnail widget

```
AssetThumbnail(
      {required this.asset,
      required this.selectedAssets,
      required this.blurhash,
      required this.controller});

  final AssetEntity asset;
  final ValueNotifier<List<File?>> selectedAssets;
  final List<String?> blurhash;
  // final VoidCallback? playVideo;
  VideoPlayerController controller;
```

then on the onpressed function for the videos

```
else {
                      widget.selectedAssets.value.clear();
                      print("video tapped");
                      widget.selectedAssets.value =
                          List.from(widget.selectedAssets.value)..add(file);

                      widget.controller = VideoPlayerController.file(file!)
                        ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
                        ..setLooping(false)
                        ..initialize()
                            .then((value) => widget.controller.play());
                    }
```

but this throws an error `LateInitializationError: Field '_controller@156439598' has not been initialized.`. but the best i've gotten is by creating the video player separately.

```
class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoScreen({
    required this.videoFile,
  });

  final File? videoFile;

  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  bool initialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initVideo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _initVideo() async {
    final video = await widget.videoFile;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(video!)
      // Play the video again when it ends
      ..setLooping(true)
      // initialize the controller and notify UI when done
      ..initialize().then((value) {
        setState(() => initialized = true);
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setVolume(0.0);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: initialized
          // If the video is initialized, display it
          ? Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
              ),
            )
          // If the video is not yet initialized, display a spinner
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

and then instead of calling the videoplayer widget i called it like so.

```
!isVideo
                                                  ? Container(
                                                      height: _height * 0.5,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                              image: FileImage(
                                                                  value
                                                                      .last!))),
                                                    )
                                                  : ValueListenableBuilder(
                                                      valueListenable:
                                                          selectedAssets,
                                                      builder: (context, value1,
                                                          child) {
                                                        return VideoScreen(
                                                            videoFile:
                                                                value1.last);
                                                      })
```

and this only works for the first selected video. it doesn't update itself.

how can i make this work?

[new development]

now i found out that to change the playing video i have to deselect the selected video then select as new. but is there a way to make the change without de selecting first?